# Getting the Binding and URI in a WCF third party application

Tags: c#, wcf, epicorerp

Hello I am working in a 3rd party application (Epicor), writing custom code to interface with it.

A class that I need to instantiate requires the Binding and URI for the constructor. I have not been able to find any kind of functionality available to me to get that info from the 3rd party application.

The custom code I am writing will be run within the 3rd party software and is not a separate assembly. I.E. the code gets built within the software's own assembly's'.

Is there any way to get/query the current Binding and URI so I can instantiate the class?

Edit: I do have access to the web.config. The software also makes use of custom bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epicor has a convention for instantiating a call to a service. You generally only really need to do this in the application if you are doing something below the adapter level in a client customization, which is generally not the best way to go about things, or if you want to call business object methods in a BPM that is NOT the business object the BPM is called from.

Perhaps if you were a bit more specific (Version of Epicor, Exactly what you are trying to do, etc) I could assist bit more specifically.

Comment: we were able to find the right kind of adapter for a Service. It seemed they changed the name and the way it works in this newer version. We are on 10. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Great!10 is considerably different from 9 but it is also considerably better in almost every measurable way. Good luck!